# Which is correct "we will soon be" or we will be soon"?

Tags: british-english

Actually someone said to me

> we are not friends

But I know we will be friends in the near future. So how should I reply?

1)

> We will soon be.

2)

> we will be soon.

Which one seems nice and which one is actually correct ?

Answer (score 2):

In English, there's some flexibility where to put an adverb. It can go before or after the verb, and in the case of verb phrases like this, it can go in the middle. That is, "We will be soon", "We will soon be", and "We soon will be" are all valid and all mean the same thing.

Where you have to be careful is when there is more than one verb in the sentence and the adverb could modify either verb. For example:

"I repeatedly told you to brush your teeth."

The thing that is repeated is the telling.

"I told you to repeatedly brush your teeth."

The thing this is repeated is the brushing.

"I told you repeatedly to brush your teeth."

Most English speakers would understand this to mean that the telling is repeated, but it could be read that the brushing is repeated.

Not the best example, I know I've heard better ones, but I can't think of one at the moment.